# How can I dynamically offset an Azure Dashboard's date range to show the previous 30-60 days of information?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-dashboard

I am using Azure Service bus to collect metrics for my web service. I want to show data on my Azure dashboard for the previous 60 days. From [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/monitor-service-bus#analyzing-metrics), I understand that I cannot do that in one chart, I need to create two charts to achieve this:

> Azure Monitor metrics data is available for 90 days. However, when creating charts only 30 days can be visualized. For example, if you want to visualize a 90 day period, you must break it into three charts of 30 days within the 90 day period.

Currently I have an Azure dashboard that shows the last 30 days of information, with granularity set to 1 day.

This is the part of the JSON for the dashboard that defines this:

```
  "filters": {
    "MsPortalFx_TimeRange": {
      "model": {
        "format": "utc",
        "granularity": "1d",
        "relative": "43200m"
      }
    }
  }
```

How do I create a second chart that shows the *next* 30 days? Can I include an offset in the above code? I cannot see a reference to this in the documentation.